# Background image won't center in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

If anyone can help me with this problem, I would be super grateful.

I have the [this site](http://srix.peachtreecollective.com) on a staging link. All is working great in Safari and Firefox. However in Internet Explorer (version 9 I believe), the background image appears to far to the right, i.e. not in the center.

image of misbehaving IE:

[image: misbehaving IE]

As each page has a different background image,  code is as follows

```
body {background-color:#000; color:#FFF; margin:0px; padding:0px;height:100%;}

#home {background:url(../images/Background2.jpg) top center no-repeat;background-color:#000;}
```

For internet explorer v9 or less, I have included:

```
#home {text-align:center;}
```

I have read through other posts but can't seem to find an answer. Thanks very much for your input!

Comment: I am using IE8 and I dont see that result. it could be resolution issues?

Comment: I think you should probably review the width set in your .row class. Looks like the problem might be in there somewhere. min-width:755px; max-width:1140px; width:100% ?

Answer (score 1):

Probabbly the implicit position of background in IE si to left and in Chrome for center. 
Try using `background-position:center center`.

Comment: thanks! the order of the position seems to fix it. `background-position:center top`.